# Sum of two array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, addition

I have two different `NSMutableArray` that contains some elements. Now I want the sum of each array's elements and also the result of the array's addition. How can I proceed?

Comment: What's the difference between "sum of each array's element" and "result of array's addition"?

Comment: do you want arr3[n]=arr1[n]+arr2[n] or sum_arr1 also sum_arr2 ?

Comment: What is the sum of an array? The union?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya sir i want arr3[n]=arr1[n]+arr2[n]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *firstArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

NSArray *secondArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10",@"20",@"30", nil];

NSMutableArray *sumArray=[NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<[firstArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *newValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",([[firstArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue] + [[secondArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue])];
    [sumArray addObject:newValue];
}

NSLog(@"sum=%@",sumArray);
```

Output is :

```
sum=(
    11,
    22,
    33
)
```

NOTE: both firstArray & secondArray must be of same size, and contain integers as string. Otherwise you need to modify...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `for loop` for this implementation.  Get each element with `objectAtIndex` and then make addition simple.

Comment: hmm..... Just make our logic..don't use others code and copy+paste you will get sharp mind and knowledge..